# How to make a different flip animation using CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation

I would like to make an animation using CSS3 that flips an element in 3D space as an intro animation. A google search will reveal many different web sites explaining how to do a flip animation - here is the top result : http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

But the problem is this is not how I want it to look. All of these flips have the center of the flip down the middle like a revolving door hinged in the center.

The flip animation that I want should start out like an open door (not visible because it is perpendicular to the screen) with the hinge on the left - then the door closes and you see the front of the closed door, and then it stops there. In my case, the user will click a button then this element will appear using the animation as an intro.

The solution should use CSS3 (javascript is ok too), and it is OK to only work in Webkit (I'll be doing some completely different animation on other browsers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `transform-origin`: `-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%`on `.flipper`. Just watch compatibility. caniuse.com doesn't list `transform-origin`. Remember vendor prefixing.

Comment: Thanks - `webkit-transform-origin: 0% 50%` is what I was looking for.

Comment: Actually support for this is quite good. It's supported unprefixed by IE10, FF16+ and Opera 12.1+. And with the corrresponding prefixes by IE9, FF3.5+, Opera 10.5+, Safari 3.1+ and any version of Chrome.